# Exacttarget A/B Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there any way to a/b test triggered send emails? I'm redesigning our transactional emails and want to a/b test them, but we use a triggered send definition in order to send out the emails. Any way to set up the send definitions to a/b test emails?

Answer (score 2):

The A/B Test module only works for mass sends. If you want to A/B test a triggered send you will need to either create an email with dynamic content, or two different triggered sends.

For testing subject lines, from names, or preheaders two triggered sends will have to be created. Each of these is bundled with the Triggered Send Definition object, and cannot be change without updating the triggered send.

For testing content areas you could use dynamic content on a standard editor email based on a profile attribute or use AMPScript in an HTML based email.

Answer (score 1):

Currently ExactTarget's A/B testing feature allows you to test the following conditions:

- Subject lines - create two different subject lines and track which subject performs better.
- Emails - create two different emails and track which email performs better.
- Content areas - create two different content areas and track which content performs better.
- From names - create two different from names and track which from name performs better.
- Send dates/times - select two different days of the week and/or times to send and track which time performs better.
- Preheaders - create two different preheaders and track which preheader performs better.

[Here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-GB/documentation/exacttarget/ab_testing/) is the documentation for that.

There is not a way for you to perform A/B testing on triggered sends, however.